# get values from href link using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have to split values from href link.

my href link as follows

```
var val =location.href      // outputs http://localhost:8080/index.html?username=test@gmail.com&joid=68
```

i want to get `username` value and `joid` value separately.

I tried following but not working

```
var emailrogh= val.split("&");

email=emailrogh[0];

var idrough=emailrogh[1].split("=");

var id=idrough[1];
```

how can i extract `test@gmail.com` and `68`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method

```
var my_link = location.search.substring().split("&");
var email = my_link[0].split("=");
email = email[1];
var id = my_link[1].split("=");
id = id[1];
alert(email);
alert(id);
```

I hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

For the "username" parameter :

`url.split("username=")[1].split("&")[0]` returns "test@gmail.com".

Same for "joid" :

`url.split("joid=")[1]` returns "68".

Edit: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/2629998) for a more reliable way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to get the URl from the href attribute.

```
var wholeString = $("#MyAncId").attr('href');
```

then use the following method to get the Querystring value

```
function getParameterByName(wholeString, name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(wholeString);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

[Source:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)DextOr

Answer (score 1):

You can use following :

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/index.html?username=test@gmail.com&joid=68"; 
var vars = {}, key;
var querystring = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
for(var i = 0; i < querystring.length; i++){
        key = querystring[i].split('=');
        vars[key[0]] = key[1];
}
console.log( vars);
```

Output would be  :

```
Object {username: "test@gmail.com", joid: "68"}
```

Here is the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/uEqZs/

Answer (score 1):

```
function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}​
```

And this is how you can use this function assuming the URL is,

```
 "http://samplepage.com/?technology=jquery&blog=jquerybyexample".
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this small & clean function:

```
function getValue(name) {
  var filter = new RegExp( name + "=([^&]+)" );
  return unescape( window.location.match(filter)[1] );
}

var username = getValue("username");
var joid = getValue("joid");
```

**See** [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hallaji/Aqzh8/)

Answer (score 1):

use this function

```
function getParameterByName(name) 
{
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

this function will return your value directly.

for eg. for your link

```
index.html?names=priya@gmail.com&id=68
```

use this function as

```
var email = getParameterByName("names");
var id = getParameterByName("id");
```

values would be

```
email = "priya@gmail.com";
id = "68";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help

```
var loc_name = "http://localhost:8080/index.html?username=test@gmail.com&joid=68&test=test";
var get_params = (loc_name.split("?")[1]).split("&");
var contents = [];
for(var i= 0; i < get_params.length ; i++){
    contents[(get_params[i].split("=")[0])] = get_params[i].split("=")[1];
}
console.log(contents['username']);
console.log(contents['joid']);
console.log(contents['test']);
```

This will parse the query string in to an array. I have got the following output in console

```
test@gmail.com
68 
test
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

var id=val .match(/username=(.*?)(?=(&|$))/)[1]